# mysql: specific item to be first and then to sort the rest chronologically to end then chronologically from beginning

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have the following table:

```
friends
_______

id    name
1     johnny
2     tam
3     slick
4     mat
5     Rhanda
6     Tommy
7     ike
8     Spencer
9     Alan
```

I want to get all the friends list but I want the id 5 to be the first item in the list. I want the next item to follow chronologically until the end. Then the list start from the beginning until all results have been returned. So it should end like this...

```
friends
_______

id    name
5     Rhanda
6     Tommy
7     ike
8     Spencer
9     Alan
1     johnny
2     tam
3     slick
4     mat
```

I have found and tried this but as you can imagine it's only returning the first item and then ordering the rest from 1 up. I have searched and worked on this for 2 days now and really could use some help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
order by (id >= 5) desc, id
```

This puts all ids 5 or greater first.  Then it sorts each of the parts in ascending order.

MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers in an integer context, with 0 for false and 1 for true.  So, to put the true values first, `desc` is needed.

Comment: THANKS! It works exactly like I needed it to... however I don't understand why... it seems like it should be asc instead of desc. If you can further assist me in understanding this I sure would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an expression to order clause like this:

```
select id, name from table
order by
         case when id >= 5 then 0 else 1 end
        , id
```

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't get it to work... is this SQL only? I am using mysql and it had some issues with the syntax.